# why is this query returning entire blog-posts

Tags: wp-query

I have tow WP_Query loops running on a page. The first query displays the sticky posts and the second query is set according to meta_value. The trouble I am having is when there is no-sticky posts, the query seems to display all the available posts, which is definitely no what I need. I need it to display nothing found, if there are no posts found according to query.

```
 $com_soon = array( 
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts'),
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'cat' => 2
                );

                $cs_profiles = new WP_Query($com_soon);
                if ($cs_profiles->have_posts()) :
                while ($cs_profiles->have_posts()) : $cs_profiles->the_post();?>
                //the loop here 
                endwhile; else:
                echo 'NOTHING FOUND';
                endif;
```

I guess this is some wp fallback mechanism. Is there any way I could avoid this because the if-have-posts doesnot seem to work here.

Comment: Never mind, found a [solution here at codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts#Display_Sticky_Posts). For those who may stumble on the same issue.

Comment: It would be great if you can post your proper solution as an answer. You can also score yourself some reputation here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below [from the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts#Display_Sticky_Posts) suggest that it would just display the first sticky post. **If there are none, it wont return anything**. Whatever your use case is please apply the logic accordingly.

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => $sticky,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( isset($sticky[0]) ) {
    // insert here your stuff...
}
```